# How to execute a program within my program in C++ in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I am writing a C++ program and I would like to execute a fortune telling program inside of the one I am writing. My program will run the fortune telling program and return a fortune to the user. How do I go about doing this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you know how to use `system()`?

Comment: I am very new to this particular subject so I am not familiar with it. How does it work?

Comment: Try `man system` from command line

Comment: As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, do some research on your own, like e.g. using your question title in a websearch. What you're asking about is not uncommon at all and it should be easy to find solutions/examples.

Comment: Knowing where to find and how to read technical documentation is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `system` allows you to call another program with arguments.

`system` is defined in `stdlib.h` as:

```c
int system(const char *command);
```

`system` take a shell command with arguments as `const char*` and returns the code returned by the command.

As you are using C++, you should include C++ header of `stdlib.h` , `cstdlib` and use `std::system` instead of `system` .

So, a minimal example of the use of `system` :

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    return std::system("fortune");
}
```

Note that `system` takes `const char*` , not `std::string` . So to pass an `std::string` , pass it like this:

```cpp
std::string command = "fortune";
std::system(command.c_str());
```

This is not required if you directly pass a double-quoted string like `"fortune"` .

Also note that calling a shell command to do a task is a bad practice unless you have a specific reason of it.